# Port is shown as "open", then as "filtered" on CentOS Stream 8

Tags: centos, nmap, port

I have made a fresh install of CentOS Stream 8 on a machine. This machine needs to connect to a Foreman Smart Proxy on port 443.

If I run `nmap` immediately after machine boots up, it sees the port as **open**:

```
[root@centos8stream ~]# nmap mysmartproxy -p443
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-04-06 15:52 CEST
Nmap scan report for mysmartproxy (10.11.12.13)
Host is up (-0.18s latency).
rDNS record for 10.11.12.13: mysmartproxy.myorg.org

 
PORT STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open https
MAC Address: 00:11:22:33:AA:BB (VMware)


Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.51 seconds
```

However, if `nmap` is run a few seconds after, it sees the port as **filtered**:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https
```

The machine manages to connect on port 443 to the Smart Proxy with no issue. However, I need that `nmap` sees the port as open, as there are health checks that depend on it.

- Connections to port 443 from all machines in the subnet are open on the Smart Proxy. There is no other firewall blocking the communication. When running `nmap` from other machines with OS different from CentOS Stream 8 within the same network, it always sees the port as open.
- Disabling SELinux on the machine has no effect.
- Disabling `firewalld` on the machine has no effect. `nftables` and any other firewall are disabled.
- IP forwarding is disabled on the machine.

What is the reason of this strange behaviour? I thought it must be a service that loads after the boot but so far I couldn't pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that having `nmap` make a full-open (TCP Connect) scan via the flag `-sT` makes it see the port as open. So my issue is solved. However, this does not explain the *reason* of the change in behaviour after the machine boots. If someone has ideas I'd be interested to hear them.